# How can I override a getter on a property when using Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I want to be able to override the getter on a string property on one of my core data models and inside the getter I need to find out what the value is for that property.

```
@interface LabTest : NSManagedObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *status;
@end

@implementation LabTest

@dynamic status;

- (NSString *)status {
    NSString *tempStatus = [super valueForKey:@"status"];
    //do some checking here
    return tempStatus;
}

@end
```

The code above crashes the process. I have tried a few different things, but I think they all end up in an infinite loop with the program crashing with a code of 139.

What is the correct way to access a core data member in the getter like this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried `[self primitiveValueForKey:@"status"]` instead of `[super valueForkey:@"status"]`?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is looking for a little more info on how to override getter methods and landed on this page...

Inside of your property definition you can specify getter and setter methods as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, getter = getterMethodName, setter = setterMethodName) NSString *someString;
```

You can specify the getter only, the setter only, or both.

Answer (score 1):

The managed object creator in x-code has a checkbox that is normally unchecked just for this purpose.

[Validation Methods http://www.nwcode.com/img/ValidationMethods.png](http://www.nwcode.com/img/ValidationMethods.png)

Comment: I am not quite doing validation, since I still want to return a value, I just may want to change it a little in some cases.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a really handy Xcode Snippets menu (Xcode 12 has a <kbd>+</kbd> button in the top right) that has great snippets for overriding lots of common Core Data code, including KVO-compliant accessors for object-types (getters + setters).

[image: GIF demo]